# Анимация падающего снега (Python 3.8.5)

Tags: python

У меня есть класс, который вызывается из 2-х разных объектов одновременно, но он выполняется по очереди.

```
import os
import time
import random


Limiter = 24

os.system("cls")

class SnowObject:
    def MovePosition(self):
        global Limiter
        for i in range(Limiter):
            print("\n" * int(i) + " " * int(self.Ypos) + str(self.Mesh))
            time.sleep(float(self.Time))
            os.system("cls")

    def __init__(self,Time,Ypos,Mesh):
        self.Time = Time
        self.Ypos = Ypos
        self.Mesh = Mesh

Snow_1 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
Snow_1.MovePosition()

Snow_2 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
Snow_2.MovePosition()


input()
```

Мой код делает анимацию из (print'а) снежинки. И мне понадобился черновик кода, который будит вызываться для каждой снежинки и я обратился к ютубу. Мне подсказали использовать class, но он работает не так как я хочу...

```
Переменные:
Limiter - лимит, который будет использован в for.
Time- время для time.sleep.
Ypos - координата Y. Позиция для Mesh по координате Y.  
Mesh - что будет отображаться на экране (В моем случае - это "*").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы пустить несколько снежинок можно использовать threading

```
import os
import time
import random
from threading import Thread

Limiter = 24

os.system("cls")

class SnowObject:
    def MovePosition(self):
        global Limiter
        for i in range(Limiter):
            print("\n" * int(i) + " " * int(self.Ypos) + str(self.Mesh))
            time.sleep(float(self.Time))
            os.system("cls")

    def __init__(self,Time,Ypos,Mesh):
        self.Time = Time
        self.Ypos = Ypos
        self.Mesh = Mesh

Snow_1 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
th = Thread(target=Snow_1.MovePosition)
th.start()

Snow_2 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
th_2 = Thread(target=Snow_2.MovePosition)
th_2.start()


input()
```

Или вместо

```
    Snow_1 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
    th = Thread(target=Snow_1.MovePosition)
    th.start()
    
    Snow_2 = SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*")
    th_2 = Thread(target=Snow_2.MovePosition)
    th_2.start()
```

Использовать:

```
for _ in range(5):
    Thread(target= SnowObject(0.5,random.randint(0,80),"*").MovePosition).start()
```

Comment: Edward Grachev, Спасибо большое!